# ubuntu doesn't recognize windows on installation

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I want to install Linux besides my Windows 7.I'm installing from a dvd, But when I get into the installation menu, it tells me that this "pc doesn't have an OS installed". Although I already have a Win7 installed. I have 5 partitions from the same disk on my PC

Here is what I see under win7:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/80GZv.jpg]

I googled for it 3 days, and no solution is right to me. That is why I ask here. I tried when installing ubuntu and centos, and both of them don't show me the Win7.

This is what `sudo fdisk -l` gives:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAcSR.png]

`gparted` shows one unallocated drive of 298Go

I also tried this command:

```
root@ubuntu:~# os-prober
/dev/sda1:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain
root@ubuntu:~#
```

and even if i do "something else" in the instalation then it shows only one partion just like gparted

plz help and thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you are trying to install Ubuntu? Are you using a Live CD? If so, can't you just select the empty partition and install Ubuntu there?

Comment: thanks for reply... i tryed installing ubuntu 14 from a dvd and centos 7 from a usb and both don't show the free partion, they are showing the entire disk instead, i even formated the "free" partion to ext3 from windows but still doesn't show in "something else"

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not aware of the subject, you probably have a dynamic disk. Please use a `Live CD` and while you are in `Ubuntu`, open up a terminal and type:

```
sudo fixparts /dev/sda
```

Comment: I alreadydid it and it showed me this 
"Warning: 0xEE partition doesn't start on sector 1. This can cause problems in some OSes." than it waits for an entry so i did "p" and it showed all my partions

Comment: There's a similar thread here http://superuser.com/questions/744916/ubuntu-14-04-installer-doesnt-show-existing-partitions with many possible solutions. Instead of listing them here, you can check them and inform in the topic whether your problem was solved.

Comment: thank you but i've already read the thread and riyed everything .... i just verified now that my disk is not dynamic but basic.